# PowerShell functions

Tags: powershell

What I understood is "Functions in PowerShell scripting are named code block which enables an easy way to organize the script commands."

& Define using:

```
Function [Scope Type:]<Function name>
```

For Example:

```
Function Test
{
    Write-Host "Test method"
} 
Test
```

Functions with parameters

Example:

```
Function Test( $msg)
{
    Param ([string] $msg)
    Write-Host "$msg"
} 
Test "Test method"
```

Output:

```
Test method
```

Parameter types:

1. Named params: `Param ([int] $first,[int] $second)`
2. Positional Params: `$args[0], $args[1]`
3. Switch params: `Param([Switch] $one,[Switch] $two)`
4. Dynamic params: `Set-Item -path alias:OpenNotepad -value c:\windows\notepad.exe`

How do these "switch parameters" work in PowerShell scripting?

Comment: [PowerShell Advanced Function Parameter Attributes - Switch Parameters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15994.powershell-advanced-function-parameter-attributes.aspx#Switch_Paramters)

Comment: Are you asking a question or providing a tutorial?

Comment: I meant both. i.e. providing whatever information I know and asking whatever I do not know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's like a Boolean, but you don't have to (but can) pass `$true` or `$false` to it. Example:

```
function Test-SwitchParam
{
    Param(
        [Switch] $one,
        [Switch] $two
    )

    if ($one)
    {
        Write-Host "Switch one is set"
    }

    if ($two)
    {
        Write-Host "Switch two is set"
    }
}
```

Now you can call the function like:

```
Test-SwitchParam -one
```

The switch `$one` will be `$true`, because it is set, and `$two` will be false.